# What are the top three conferences relevant to SF?

Tags: discussion

What are the top three IT conferences that are relevant to infrastructure operations?

There is likely to be debate here but we should be able to filter out several useful conferences where SF could be promoted.

One conference per answer is probably appropriate to enable voting.

Note: This question is specifically in response to Robert's recent blog posting [A Recipe to Promote your Site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/).

Comment: Working for a shoe-string department with no training/conference budget (first over the side when the budget cuts arrived) means I don't know diddly about what the good conferences are.

Comment: I sympathize.  I've been having to focus more on local events myself over the past couple years.

Comment: What part of the world are you asking about? I think you may have forgotten that this is a global web site.

Comment: If you have a conference in Australia to recommend that is of the appropriate level of significance within our profession, I am certain that it would be worth considering as well, John.  People travel all over the world for notable events.

Comment: Yeah well, I'm not actually aware of such an event in Australia. At least not one I'd travel more than a 100Km to attend.

Comment: @John @Warner - maybe this is an oppertunity to start one? I wouldn't mind spending a weekend at Noosa ;) (Or perhaps somewhere more affordable, if we must).

Comment: @Farseeker, other than the Sage-AU conference (in Hobart this year) what else is there?

Comment: @John - no idea, when I started this job I was promised the oppertunity to go to conferences and courses to brush up on my skills but 5 years later the job interview was the only time it was mentioned ;)

Answer (score 3):

USENIX's [Large Installation System Administration](http://www.usenix.org/events/lisa10/) conference.

Answer (score 0):

[Velocity Web Performance and Operations](http://en.oreilly.com/velocity2010) conference.

Answer (score 0):

[Ohio LinuxFest](http://www.ohiolinux.org/).